# Error al inyectar modulo para borrar historial en ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tratando de borrar el historial de una app hecha con ionic cree un módulo nuevo, pero al tratar de inyectarlo se me genera el siguiente problema

> ionic.bundle.min.js:40 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=unicesarApp&p1=Erro…%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js%3A74%3A503)

### index.html

```
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-Cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="App/login.js"></script>
    <script src="App/historial.js"></script>
```

### login.js

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic', 'historialApp'])
       .controller('formulario', formulario)
       .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
       .config(config);


config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'historial'];

.state('menuestu',{
             url: '/menuestu',
             templateUrl: "Templates/Estudiante/menuestu.html",
             controller: "historialApp"
       })
```

### historial.js

```
angular.module('historialApp', ['ionic'])
   .controller('historial', historial);

historial.$inject = ['$ionicHistory'];

function historial($ionicHistory){
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();    
}
```

### menu.html - template

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced" align-title="center">
<p class="title">Menu Estudiante</p>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-view>    
    <ion-content has-header="true"> 

    <div class="container" ng-controller="historial">


        </div>

    </div>

</ion-content>
```

Al momento de inyectar el módulo y tratar de llamar al controlador que agregué a ese módulo para borrar el historial se crea un error, y también se crea un error si lo quitara y lo llamara desde ***app.js***, pues cuando trata de ingresar a la vista de los menús sale el error y no avanza.

Quisiera saber que es lo que esta mal, si es la forma de inyectar o de llamar el controlador, gracias de antemano.

Comment: El mensaje de error que pones no parece estar completo. También tu código no parece tener problemas. Si el problema es con un módulo deberías poner los ficheros js con la definición de los módulos. Las vistas html no son necesarias.

Comment: @devconcept pues los ficheros estan puse los html con la intencion que se viera, pero de igual forma, viene siendo una pregunta parecida a una que hice ya, tambien probe lo que me dijiste la otra vez para salir de la app pero no me funciono

Comment: Te explico. Si el error viene de inyectar un módulo el código html que tienes tiene poca relevancia para responder la pregunta. El comentario lo hice para que tuvieras mas probabilidades de obtener respuesta porque la verdadera causa que es el error que te está saliendo no está lo suficiente claro. Quizas la otra pregunta no tuvo respuesta porque posteaste todo el código y es dificil de reproducir tu problema de esa forma.

Comment: @devconcept ya coloque el codigo del modulo con el controlador que quiero inyectar, para luego ponerlo en los **$state**

Comment: @devconcept ya esta puesto el error con pelos y señales, el fihcero js del historial y pues el html lo quitare en la edicion, dime si esta suficiente ese error

Comment: Si. Ya comienza a tener sentido. Intenta usar el `ionic.bunde.js` en lugar de usar `ionic.bundle.min.js` para que los mensajes se puedan leer y publica el error que te saldrá esta vez.

Comment: @devconcept ahora sale este error, al menos sale mas completo, 

**ionic.bundle.js:13380 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module unicesarApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: historial**

Comment: @devconcept, sera que debe ser algo que no esta siendo llamado de la manera correcta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas intentando usar un factory o un servicio en un `config block`. Eso es un error ya que:

> Un módulo es una colección de bloques de ejecución y configuración los cuales son aplicados a la aplicación durante el proceso de inicialización. en su forma más simple un módulo consiste en una colección de dos tipos de bloques:
>
> 1. Bloques de configuración - Son ejecutados en la fase de configuración y registro de providers. **Sólo providers y constantes pueden ser inyectados en bloques de configuración**. Esto se hace para prevenir la instanciación accidental de servicios antes de que hayan sido configurados completamente.
> 2. Bloques de ejecución - Son ejecutados despues que el injector es creado y se usan para arrancar la aplicación. **Sólo instancias y constantes pueden inyectarse en bloques de ejecución**. Esto se hace para prevenir que se hagan más configuraciones al sistema durante la fase de run-time.

Si te fijas en los fragmentos resaltados en negrita te dice que solo lo que haya sido declarado con `.constant` y `.provider` puede ejecutarse en un `config block` mientras que en los `run blocks` no puedes usar lo que haya sido declarado con `.provider`

Simplemente reemplaza esta linea en el fichero login.js

```
angular.module('unicesarApp', ['ionic', 'historialApp'])
   .controller('formulario', formulario)
   .service('obtenerDatos', obtenerDatos)
   //.config(config); => quita el config y pon un run
   .run(config)
```

A los ojos de angular [`$ionicHistory`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) es un factory como cualquier otro aunque haya sido declarado en una librería. Los providers son fácilmente identificables porque terminan en *Provider* como por ejemplo el [`$ionicConfigProvider`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/).

**Nota:** Yo usé usa notación `.run(config)` ya que `config` es una función que tienes declarada en tu código. Si renombras la variable será menos confuso pero para angular no tiene relevancia ya que a este sólo le importa el tipo de objeto que estas tratando de inyectar en el bloque (si es un factory, un service, etc).

**Actualización**

Al responder la pregunta pensé que `historial` era un factory que habías intentado agregar al módulo. Si este es un `controller` lo estas usando mal ya que los controlers se agregan a un módulo automáticamente al ser declarados usando la notación

```
angular.module('miModulo').controller('miController');
// ya el módulo "miModulo" contiene un controller llamado "miController"
// en el ejemplo "miModulo" ya había sido declarado antes
```

Luego cuando declaras otro módulo y le pones dependencias los controlers de un módulo se agregan al otro también

```
// Se declara un módulo "miApp" y se le especifica que "miModulo" es una dependencia
angular.module('miApp', ['miModulo']);
// El controller "miController" se agrega a "miApp" automáticamente
// o los puedes agregar al módulo "miApp" directamente
```

Comment: Estoy probando, ya te aviso @devconcept

Comment: obtengo este error ahora, **Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProviderProvider <- $stateProvider**

Comment: Lee mi respuesta de nuevo. Estas intentando inyectar un factory y un provider juntos. **Esa combinación no es posible**. Lo que tienes que hacer aquí es dividirlos en 2 y ejecutar parte de código en un `run` y parte en un `config`

Comment: Quizas me equivoque pero creo que estás tratando de inyectar un controller en la parte que dice `config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'historial'];`. 'historial' es un controller o un factory en tu app?

Comment: historial es un controller tal cual lo especifico en el codigo que puse cuando edite @devconcept

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Revisa el update de mi respuesta

Comment: Bueno voy a probar lo que me dices, y te comento, de paso, ayer realice una pregunta debido a lo que me dijiste sobre inyectar [inyectar dependencias](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6669/formas-correctas-de-usar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-de-dependencias-angular?noredirect=1#comment12160_6669)

Comment: Perfecto @devconcept, ojala puedas echarle un ojo a la otra pregunta que realice