# Formas correctas de usar la inyección de dependencias angular

Tags: angularjs

Tengo una serie de dudas con respecto a como se deben inyectar las dependencias. Quisiera saber:

1. Como se inyecta un modulo, un controlador, una fabrica(factory), un servicio (services), un proveedor (provider), y que orden se debe seguir (Ejemplo, factory y provider no se pueden inyectar juntos)
2. Como se inyectan desde diferentes archivos, y que orden deben seguir en el archivo principal

### archivo1.js

```
angular.module('MiPeticion',['Dependencias a utilizar'])
       .services('MiServicio', MiServicio);

MiServicio.$inject = ['Dependencias a utilizar'];

function MiServicio (){
   Codigo
};
```

### Achivo2.js

```
angular.module('MiAplicacion',['Dependencias a utilizar'])
       .controller('MiControlador', MiControlador);

MiControlador.$inject = ['Dependencias a utilizar'];

function MiControlador (){
   Codigo
};
```

### Archivo3.js

```
angular.module('MiProceso',['Dependencias a utilizar'])
       .factory('MiFabrica', MiFabrica);

MiFabrica.$inject = ['Dependencias a utilizar'];

function MiFabrica (){
   Codigo
};
```

Cual es la forma correcta, y el orden.

**Gracias de antemano**

Comment: Hola, no se pero creo que haces muuuuchas preguntas para contestarlas de una vez.

Comment: @WilfredoP, que mas, dejame edito a ver que tal, andas en el chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La primera pregunta, la injección de dependencias se puede hacer de 2 formas... primero y las mas común es pasando las dependencias como parámetros, para ello se usa la propiedad $inject, o se usa el array de dependencias en la definición...

yo recomiendo tratar de usar el $inject... por que el código es mas limpio, ademas que se ve mucho mejor en *TypeScript* (considerando que *Angular 2.0* esta hecho en *TypeScript*)

...

Con respecto a como se injecta desde diferentes archivos; al ser javascript solo debes incluirlos todos en el archivo HTML, con respecto a un orden, no creo que haya un orden definido para eso, como sea ya que para las referencias se usan cadenas no es necesario ponerlas en un orden determinado, claro que hay una excepcion el archivo donde defines el modulo debe ir primero que los archivos donde defines controladores, services para ese modulo

Comment: Ok , gracias, osea, el archivo donde va el mudlo principal de mi app, que por ejemplo que se llama CalcApp, debe ir seguido de todoas las librerias que valla a usar el cual de este vaya depnder, luego debajo de el todo respecto lo que se vaya inyectar a el, gracias

Comment: No es lo mismo escribir `.$inject = ['$scope', $rootScope]` que `.$inject = ['$rootScope', $scope]`. Los inyectables son invocados **en el mismo orden que se referencian** da igual cual es el método de inyección que se usa. El orden de los módulos tambien importa y por lo general se ponen los que tienen dependencias **despues que su dependencia ya ha sido incluida**, ej `.module('app', ['data'])` el módulo `data` se incluye primero y luego el módulo `app`. El orden si importa.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario... pero la pregunta no iba relacionada en el orden de las referencias en el controlador/servicio, sino en el orden de los archivos js